# How can I split a string into chunks of two characters each in Perl?

Tags: regex, arrays, perl, split

How do I take a string in Perl and split it up into an array with entries two characters long each?

I attempted this:

```
@array = split(/../, $string);
```

but did not get the expected results.

Ultimately I want to turn something like this

```
F53CBBA476
```

in to an array containing

```
F5 3C BB A4 76
```

Answer (score 61, accepted):

```
@array = ( $string =~ m/../g );
```

The pattern-matching operator behaves in a special way in a list context in Perl.  It processes the operation iteratively, matching the pattern against the remainder of the text after the previous match.  Then the list is formed from all the text that matched during each application of the pattern-matching.

Answer (score 43):

If you really must use `split`, you can do a :

```
grep {length > 0} split(/(..)/, $string);
```

But I think the fastest way would be with `unpack` :

```
unpack("(A2)*", $string);
```

Both these methods have the "advantage" that if the string has an odd number of characters, it will output the last one on it's own.

Comment: Since it looks like he is working with hex characters, so this is a bit of a moot point, but A only works for ASCII characters.  The split should work for any encoding, but you might want to add a /s to the regex so "\n" will be matched by ".".

Comment: Should be `a2`, not `A2`. The former strips trailing whitespace, which is at best superfluous.

Answer (score 7):

Actually, to catch the odd character, you want to make the second character optional:

```
@array = ( $string =~ m/..?/g );
```

Comment: yup, but it's way slower than unpack.

Answer (score 7):

The pattern passed to `split` identifies what *separates* that which you want. If you wanted to use split, you'd use something like

```
my @pairs = split /(?(?{ pos() % 2 })(?!))/, $string;
```

or

```
my @pairs = split /(?=(?:.{2})+\z)/s, $string;
```

Those are rather poor solutions. Better solutions include:

```
my @pairs = $string =~ /..?/sg;  # Accepts odd-length strings.

my @pairs = $string =~ /../sg;

my @pairs = unpack '(a2)*', $string;
```

Answer (score 1):

I see a more-intuitive (if perhaps less-efficient) way to solve this issue: slice-off the required 2-character strings from the string with "substr" and push them onto the array with "push":

```
# Start with a string (a hex number in this case):
my $string = "526f62626965204861746c6579";

# Declare an array to hold the desired 2-char snippets:
my @array; 

# Snip snippets from string and put in array:
while ($string) {push @array, substr($string,0,2,"");}

# Say, those look like ASCII codes, don't they?
for (@array) {print chr(hex($_));}
```

Run that and see what it prints. :-)