# perl - split string into 2-character groups

Tags: regex, perl, split, text-processing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I split a string into chunks of two characters each in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372370/how-can-i-split-a-string-into-chunks-of-two-characters-each-in-perl)

I wanted to split a string into an array grouping it by 2-character pieces:

```
  $input = "DEADBEEF";
  @output = split(/(..)/,$input);
```

This approach produces every other element empty.

```
  $VAR1 = '';
  $VAR2 = 'DE';
  $VAR3 = '';
  $VAR4 = 'AD';
  $VAR5 = '';
  $VAR6 = 'BE';
  $VAR7 = '';
  $VAR8 = 'EF';
```

How to get a continuous array?

```
  $VAR1 = 'DE';
  $VAR2 = 'AD';
  $VAR3 = 'BE';
  $VAR4 = 'EF';
```

(...other than getting the first result and removing every other row...)

Comment: Thanks, Ed - probably this is the correct solution, feel free to close the question.

Comment: I added an answer for you in the linked thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can easily filter out the empty entries with:

```
@output = grep { /.+/ } @output ;
```

Edit:
You can obtain the same thing easier:

```
$input = "DEADBEEF";
my @output = ( $input =~ m/.{2}/g );
```

Edit 2 another version:

```
$input = "DEADBEEF";
my @output = unpack("(A2)*", $input);
```

Regards

Comment: `a2`, not `A2`. The latter strips trailing whitespace, which is superfluous at best.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$input = "DEADBEEF";
@output = ();

while ($input =~ /(.{2})/g) {
  push @output, $1;
}
```

Comment: add the /s flag, or newlines will be skipped past (and odd characters before them)