# Split a String into Equal Length Chunk in Perl

Tags: perl, split

Let's say I have string of length in multiple of 3.

```
my $seq = "CTTCGAATT"; # in this case length of 9
```

Is there a way I can split it into equal length of 3?
Such that in the end I have this array:

```
$VAR = ["CTT", "CGA", "ATT"];
```

Comment: Crossposted to Perlmonks. There, three solutions were provided, with benchmarks demonstrating the unpack method to be a good choice.  http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=939987

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Take a look at the solution at [How can I split a string into chunks of two characters each in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/372370/1065232)

Especially the `unpack` might be interesting:

```
my @codons = unpack("(A3)*", $seq);
```

Answer (score 3):

Iterate over multiples of three, using `substr` to get pieces to `push` into a list.

Comment: Thanks. In practice I have around 10 million of such string to break. Substr may be  too slow?

Comment: Try it out. If it is slow, then read through the file character by character until you fill a buffer, which you push into a list. Repeat until EOF.

Answer (score 3):

```
my $str = join '', map { ('A','T','C','G')[ rand 4 ] } 0 .. 900 ; # Random string

my @codons = $str =~ /[ACTG]{3}/g;   # Process in chunks of three
                                     # '/g' flag necessary

print 'Size of @codons array : ',
        scalar @codons;              # '300'
```

Answer (score 3):

`my $str='ABCDEFGHIJKLM';`

we can use string match to get parts from the string, where minimum length is 1 and maximum is the required length, 3 or 4 or whatever

`@parts = $str =~ /(.{1,4})/g;` and we get `@parts = ['ABCD', 'EFGH', 'IJKL', 'M']`

Comment: A thousand upticks from me on this one. Thank you.