# How to chunk text "from the back" in perl.

Tags: regex, perl

I'm writing code to divide up (big) text strings "from the back" in perl (i.e. end-to-start or right-to-left) into equal-size chunks (with remainder at the front).

It's working, but this seems to be a case where perl's "it's easy/fast to do (conceptually) easy things" paradigm is breaking down.

The most elegant way I found is adapted from here:
[How do I display large numbers with commas? HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27761543/how-do-i-display-large-numbers-with-commas-html)

```
my @a = split /(?=(?:.{8})+$)/,$a;
```

But this is very slow as the strings get very large, probably due to all the necessary backtracking. Is there maybe a more efficient way using the same idea (or any regexp)?

I rejected the idea of "reverse input, process forward, reverse output" out-of-hand out of similar inefficiency concerns. But I'd welcome correction on those concerns if anyone knows anything about that.

I did do a brute-force "iteration of substr's" implementation, which was fine but inelegant.

Only slightly less elegant but also slightly faster is an implementation using `unpack` I've currently got running, as adapted from here: [Split a String into Equal Length Chunk in Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8265653/split-a-string-into-equal-length-chunk-in-perl)

```
use integer;
my $la = length($a);
my $r = $la % 8;
my @a = unpack(($r?"a$r":"")."(a8)"x($la/8), $a);
```

Pretty ugly. Even the seeming simplification `"(a8)*"` (instead of the `x`) fails because for some reason perl gives an extra `""` at the end in cases where length is less than 8, say 5, and the unpack template is `"a5(a8)*"`. (Anybody have an explanation for that "feature"? :-S)

Any better ideas for simplification without introducing inefficiency? Thanks.

Comment: In case anyone is interested, the application is bignum arithmetic, using the chunking to do "native" arithmetic where possible.

Comment: in that case, have you considered storing your numbers backwards? :)

Comment: @hobbs Yes, that was my latest thought -- just represent everything backwards internally. Until I realized that I'd have to re-reverse on every operation's arguments (inner loop) to feed them to "native" arithmetic. Sort of defeating the purpose.

Comment: I found a slight improvement: the parens around `(a8)` are superfluous. (Parens were left over from `(a8)*`).

Comment: Alternative improvement: the parens can be left in and `x` changed to `.` instead, for a space improvement.

Comment: @JeffY, since you care for performance, and task is solvable with the `unpack`... IME there is nothing faster than `pack`/`unpack` at processing raw data in Perl (except a custom XS). Yes, it looks ugly, but that can be solved by moving the code into a function. ( Benchmark: http://pastebin.com/eByQ4z3S )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best by test:

```
use integer;
my $la = length($a);
my $r = $la % 8;
my @a = unpack(($r?"a$r":"")."(a8)".($la/8), $a);
```

There seems no cleaner way to do this efficiently.

Explanation:

`use integer;` is so that `($la/8)` is truncated to integer. `int($la/8)` would do the same thing.

`$r` is the "remainder", the amount of remaining string after "dividing" it into chunks of 8.

If the string is evenly divisible by 8 (`$r==0`) there must be no "remainder" part included in `unpack`'s template, otherwise `"a$r"`: `($r?"a$r":"")`

The "quotient", or chunking, part of `unpack`'s template is: `"(a8)".($la/8)`

The last line can be replaced with the following for cleaner-looking code, at the cost of a couple more variables:

```
my $q = $la / 8;
my $tr = $r ? "a$r" : "";
my @a = unpack "$tr(a8)$q", $a;
```