# What is the best way to convert a string to a string with separators in perl

Tags: string, perl

How do I convert `$var = "000000000"` to `$var = "0_0000_0000"` in Perl ?

Comment: This question is unclear. Will your string always have 9 characters and you want the `_` after the first and fifth character? Or is there some other idea here? Please give some context. Also, usually on this site you should include some sample code of what you've already tried yourself, and we can help you as to why it isn't working. This site is not to do all of the work for you.

Comment: $var=000000000 next line: substr($var, 1, 0) = '\_' next line substr($var, 6, 0) = '\_'

Comment: Yes, the string will always be of 9 characters and the position of _ should be after the 1st and 5th character

Comment: for example: `$var =~ s/^(.)(.{4})/$1_$2_/;`

Answer (score 1):

If the string is always 9 characters long, you can just use `substr`:

```
my $var = '000000000';
substr($var, 5, 0) = '_';
substr($var, 1, 0) = '_';
```

For formatting strings of arbitrary length you could use a function like this:

```
sub format_str {
    my $str = reverse $_[0];
    $str =~ s/(.{4})(?=.)/$1_/g;
    return scalar reverse $str;
}

my $var = "000000000";
print format_str $var; # "0_0000_0000"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$var = "000000000"; 
$var2 = substr($var,0,1)."_".substr($var,1,4)."_".substr($var,5); 
print $var2;
```

Comment: A little narrative would help a lot

Answer (score 0):

For a solution for any-length string and considering efficiency issues that arise for very-long strings, please see my previous question&answer: [How to chunk text "from the back" in perl.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33721927/how-to-chunk-text-from-the-back-in-perl)

Per suggestion in comment, here is code using the idea in the linked question/answer which answers the OP question:

```
use integer;
my $la = length($var);
my $r = $la % 4;
my $q = $la / 4;
my $tr = $r ? "a$r" : "";
$var = join "_", unpack "$tr(a4)$q", $var;
```

Note: change all **three** `4`s for a different grouping size.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're asking how to insert a `_` after the first and fifth characters of a string, the following are a variety of straightforward solutions:

```
my $in  = '000000000'; 
my $out = substr($var,0,1) . '_' . substr($var,1,4) . '_' . substr($var,5);
```

```
my $in  = '000000000'; 
my $out = join('_', substr($var,0,1), substr($var,1,4), substr($var,5));
```

```
my $in  = '000000000'; 
my $out = join('_', unpack('a1 a4 a4*', $in));
```

```
my $in  = '000000000'; 
my $out = $in =~ s/^(.)(.{4})/${1}_${2}_/sr;  # 5.14+
```

```
my $in  = '000000000'; 
( my $out = $in ) =~ s/^(.)(.{4})/${1}_${2}_/s;
```

In-place:

```
my $var = '000000000'; 
$var =~ s/^(.)(.{4})/${1}_${2}_/s;
```

```
my $var = '000000000';
substr($var, 5, 0) = '_';
substr($var, 1, 0) = '_';
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is a *commify* problem that is solved in [*"How can I output my numbers with commas added?"*](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5.html#How-can-I-output-my-numbers-with-commas-added%3f), available as `perldoc -q 'commas added'`, then a similar solution will suffice, with extra parameters to define the separator and the size of the interval

You will want to read the `perlfaq` entry for other alternatives

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

print group_characters(1234567), "\n";
print group_characters('000000000', '_', 4), "\n";
print group_characters('0123456789ABCDEF', ' ', 4), "\n";

sub group_characters {
    my ($s, $sep, $n) = @_;
    $sep //= ',';
    $n   //= 3;

    1 while $s =~ s/[^$sep]+\K(?=[^$sep]{$n})/$sep/;

    $s;
}
```

#### output

```
1,234,567
0_0000_0000
0123 4567 89AB CDEF
```