# How does this Perl code split a string into three-character chunks?

Tags: regex, perl, split

I have a string that I need to split into three-character chunks.  Googling found the following code, which works fine:

```
$input = "DEADBEEF";
@output = ();
my @output = ( $input =~ m/.{3}/g );
print $_."\n" foreach (@output);
```

I am a Perl beginner; can someone explain to me what the expression `$input =~ m/.{3}/g` does?

Comment: ALWAYS `use strict` and `use warnings`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/372370/133939 for better ways to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$input - scalar variable
=~     - apply regular expression
m      - Match (in list context so return a list of matched substrings)
/      - start of expression
.      - any character
{3}    - 3 times
/      - end of expression
g      - globally
```

Comment: Thanks. I was a bit confused before. Now the regex explanation is clear.

Comment: @Quentin 
be-a-u-ti-ful, bravo!